# How do I make my character be a part of something without it seeming forced?

Tags: characters, motivation

I'm writing a Star Wars fanfiction because I wanted to practice my writing on something I love, and I decided to make a character named Alexander Ray Rullero. He's not the main character, as in he is not the character you will be following most of the time. He's the secondary main character and he will be someone who you'll probably dislike in the beginning. He's a pessimist and doesn't believe in what he's fighting for. He will always try and weasel his way out of anything  dangerous assignments and will criticize the idealistic primary main character for their hopes of a better future. He dislikes the main character because he believes their optimism is out of place in a battle as futile as the one that is the Rebels against the Empire. At least, Ray thinks the rebel's fight against the Empire is futile.

Like, the main character says "The Imperial fleet won't notice us, right? I mean, we're hidden in the most tightly packed asteroid belt I've ever seen! We'll make it out of here without a scratch!", and Ray would reply with "They have radar technology, and when they do find us, those star destroyers will do much more than just "Scratch" this lump of glorified scrap metal that we call a ship".

As you can see, it doesn't exactly seem like he wants to be a part of the Rebel Alliance. Though Ray will grow as a character, gradually becoming less pessimistic, more supportive, and eventually he'll come to the point where he thinks the Rebel cause is something worth fighting for. He'd even encourage the main character to keep fighting the Empire when they think that all is lost at one point. But that's later, and I intended to make Ray a part of the Alliance off the bat.

I feel as if I've written myself into a corner here. I want him around so that he can tell the main character that what their fighting for his hopeless, only to encourage the main character to keep fighting and never give up hope when the main character loses all optimism and nearly gives up.

If anyone could give me any ideas as to how I can make this character a part of the Rebel Alliance without it seeming as if I've forced him to be there, then that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider Han Solo in the original trilogy; he was a smuggler who was only in it for the money at first, got roped into something much larger than he had anticipated, but eventually came around to the Rebellion's side in full. Perhaps Ray ended up with the Rebellion in a similar manner, or is someone who was on the run from the Empire due to petty crimes or the like and ended up joining the Rebel Alliance out of necessity. This may even lead to some people treating him with suspicion or considering him a liability (think of the cynical/pragmatic DJ and what he did in The Last Jedi, after all), which could add depth to your story with him ultimately having to prove himself to those who don't believe it once he becomes fully committed to the Rebel cause.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set straight what exactly he doesn't like about the alliance, and what makes him support them anyway. Often one's reasons are not singular, or simple. Certain aspects might make him almost leave the alliance, but others will make him stay. Think of it like grading. He might not reach an A+ in devotion, but a D will do.
Some ideas that might help you:

- He thinks that if you want something done, you should do it yourself.
- He made a promise to someone or something.
- He doesn't understand certain things about the alliance, but believes it's the best choice concerning the circumstances.
- He doesn't believe in the ideal, but in the people.( Or vice-versa )
- He has certain skill set or knowledge that make him one of the few people to pull something off. He doesn't like doing it, but he has to.
- He has become desensitized throughout the years, and thinks their goal may not be reached in his lifetime.
- He joined a while ago, but has now become a known criminal/rebel, making him unable to leave.
- He has seen too many people die, and is difficult to breach without proving that you're going to last longer then a few months.

Mix and match to your liking.
Personally I would go for the arc that this young new MC does or achieves something that was deemed difficult to improbable. This will make him think what else has become possible with this new information/tactic/strategy/mcguffin.

"You. What. How did you...? Hold on. I need to go make a call."

Answer (score 0):

What about a revenge style back story.  He's with the rebels because he's been wronged by someone close to him who is part of the empire.

He's pessimistic because of his history, but driven to fight the empire by his anger.

Comment: Depending on how far into the Rebellion's progress, he could be a guy who was off world when that... er... unpleasentness befell Alderaan, his home.  Lore does note that surivivors were livid and joined the Death Star's destruction of the planet turned them into one of the most common groups of people in the Rebellion over night.

Answer (score 0):

He's wanted for a crime by the Empire.  It should be one that isn't a crime under the Rebels (i.e. Lots of dictatorships hate the people who point out they are incompetent) or some similar reason, he is no longer legally allowed in society in the Empire and any attempts to return are way worse than leaving the Rebels.  Perhaps he's an arms dealer who sold unknowingly to Rebellion buyers or perhaps he is just a poor guy being chased by troopers for selling death-sticks (when he was on his way home to rethink his life no less) and stowed away on the force transport that got him outta there... which was the rebel ship that is now in way over it's head...

Either way... the Rebels don't care about his criminal connections, but the Empire does.  These could be put to use... maybe he knows a Twi'lek who knows a Gamorian who knows a Hutt...   Or he can build a street smart solution to a problem that the book smart guys are over thinking.